# ESX 5.5 VM deployment

Tags: automation, virtual-machine, esx

Is it possible to deploy vm's using a csv or something similar?  I want to automate the install of about 100 servers.  The only option I have found is using powershell.  I would really like some other options though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

VCenter exposes an API, the documentation for which can be found here:

http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/sdk_pubs.html

Armed with that API and a template, you should be able to do what you want to do in the language of your choice.

Templates can be customized with a CustomizationSpec directly from the VSphere client as well, which means you can deploy directly from the template in the client.

Other options: VMware's Orchestrator or Microsoft Orchestrator with the VMware plugin.

However, is there really any reason not to use Powershell?  PowerCLI can do what you want to do and very easily.  I've deployed thousands of servers with it.

Comment: I was looking through your link but couldn't find any details on how to do the actual deploy.  I would like to see the steps involved to see if this is a viable option.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It would require me writing you a book.  The API is very rich, which is exactly why I recommend using Powershell to do your deployments.  It's much easier to learn and use PowerCLI than it is to develop a solution using the API.  If you have a prepared template and a customization spec, you could potentially deploy as many servers as you want with a single command at the PowerCLI command line.  No kidding. Don't poo-poo it till you've tried it.

Comment: Not poo pooing it.  I was just curious what the general process was.  I will look into it.  Thank you for the suggestion and link.